# Resize the window while the loop is running with SDL2 and OpenGL in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

This is my current code :

All the include

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "SceneOpenGL.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef WIN32
#include <GL/glew.h>

#else
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL3/gl3.h>

#endif

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Voiding my function

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments);
void DrawEllipse(float cx, float cy, float a, float b, int num_segments);
void Rotation(float a,float b,float r, float g_theta );
```

The main function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
SDL_Window* fenetre(0);
SDL_GLContext contexteOpenGL(0);

SDL_Event evenements;
bool terminer(false);

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Erreur lors de l'initialisation de la SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);


SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);


fenetre = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL 2.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

if(fenetre == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Erreur lors de la creation de la fenetre : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}

contexteOpenGL = SDL_GL_CreateContext(fenetre);

if(contexteOpenGL == 0)
{
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}


#ifdef WIN32

    GLenum initialisationGLEW( glewInit() );

    if(initialisationGLEW != GLEW_OK)
    {

        std::cout << "Erreur d'initialisation de GLEW : " << glewGetErrorString(initialisationGLEW) << std::endl;

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexteOpenGL);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

#endif
```

Main loop with the display of the circle and the ellipse

```
 while(!terminer)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&evenements);

    if(evenements.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
        terminer = true;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

float g_theta = 0.0f;

while (g_theta<360)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
g_theta += 1.0f;
DrawCircle(0, 0, 0.3, 50);
Rotation(0.8,0.65,0.1,g_theta);
Rotation(0.5,0.5,0.2,g_theta);
Rotation(0.1,0.1,0.01,g_theta);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(fenetre);
}
}
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexteOpenGL);
SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}
```

Function creating the circle

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
{
    float theta = 2.0 * M_PI * float(ii) / float(num_segments);

    float x_c = r * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component
    float y_c = r * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2f(x_c + cx, y_c + cy);//output vertex
}
glEnd();
}
```

Function creating the ellipse

```
    void DrawEllipse(float cx, float cy, float a, float b, int num_segments)
{
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
    {
        float theta = 2.0 * M_PI * float(ii) / float(num_segments);

        float x_e = a * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component
        float y_e = b * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component
        glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex2f(x_e + cx, y_e + cy);//output vertex
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Function that links the circle and the ellispe

```
    void Rotation(float a,float b,float r, float g_theta )
{

float x = a * cosf(g_theta * M_PI / 180.0f);
float y = b * sinf(g_theta * M_PI / 180.0f);
float d = sqrtf( x*x + y*y );

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( g_theta, 0, 0, 1 );  // rotation around the z axis
glTranslatef( d, 0, 0 );        // translation by the distance

DrawCircle(0, 0, r, 50);
glPopMatrix();

DrawEllipse(0, 0, a, b, 50);

}
```

this code displays circles moving on ellipses.

I would like to resize the window while the circles move.

I have already set the window as resizable:

```
fenetre = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL 2.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
```

But when I run the code, I can't resize.

How can I resize the window while the loop `while(!terminer)` is running ?

Comment: Before doing `if (evenements.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)`, you have to make sure that `evenements.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT`. Otherwise you might be accessing an inactive union field, which is not a good thing.

Comment: What do you mean by can't resize? Is your window manager not allowing your window corner to be dragged for resize, or maximise it? SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE should be enough for that, if it isn't the case - please make *minimal* example illustrating your problem (no GL or fancy stuff - should fit ~30 lines of code) and add that to question, as well as your SDL version, compiler, OS, window manager, etc.. And yes, your event handling is wrong, as HolyBlackCat said (plus some more - you don't want to read event if `WaitEvent` returned 0), but that shouldn't be related to resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that you have 2 nested loops, while the outer loops has an event handling, the inner loop has it not.
You current design is like this:

```
while not end

    event handling

    theta = 0
    while (theta < 360)

        theta ++;
        draw geometry
```

This causes that all the window like resize are not handled for a long period of time in the inner loop.

You have to change the design like this, to solve your issue:

```
theta = 0
while not end

    event handling

    draw geometry

    theta ++;
    if theta > 360 then theta = 0
```

Further you have to suit the viewport rectangle to the window size, every time when the size of the window has changed. This can be done by [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml):

Change the main loop of your program somehow like this:

```
int   vp_cx   = 0;
int   vp_cy   = 0;
float g_theta = 0.0f;
while(!terminer)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) );
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT: terminer = true; break;
        }
    }

    int cx, cy;
    SDL_GetWindowSize( fenetre, &cx, &cy );
    if ( vp_cx != cx || vp_cy != cy )
    {
         vp_cx = cx; vp_cy = cy;
         glViewport( 0, 0, vp_cx, vp_cy );
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    DrawCircle(0, 0, 0.3, 50);
    Rotation(0.8,0.65,0.1,g_theta);
    Rotation(0.5,0.5,0.2,g_theta);
    Rotation(0.1,0.1,0.01,g_theta);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(fenetre);

    g_theta += 1.0f;
    if ( g_theta >= 360.0f-0.001f )
      g_theta = 0.0;
}
```